# Is there a standard enum on Linux that maps to IP's protocol field?

Tags: c, linux

I could not find one but am surprised that it would not exist. Is there an already defined enum whose values (e.g. TCP, UDP, ICMP) corresponding to the protocol field of an IP header?

Comment: in user space? unless you use some packet capture library you won't see raw packets, so there's no need for such enum.

Comment: In userland there is `/etc/protocols` but I guess you mean the kernel sources...

Comment: `/usr/include/linux/in.h` or `/usr/include/netinet/in.h`? They come with `linux-libc-dev` and `libc6-dev`, anonymous enum with `IPPROTO_` prefix

Answer (score 2):

No enums, but there's `getprotoent()`, `getprotobyname()`, and `getprotobynumber()` if you want to look them up from `/etc/protocols`.

Comment: But this aren't kernel functions. They belong to the libc

Answer (score 2):

Check `linux/include/uapi/linux/in.h`:

```
/* Standard well-defined IP protocols.  */
enum {
  IPPROTO_IP = 0,       /* Dummy protocol for TCP       */
#define IPPROTO_IP      IPPROTO_IP
  IPPROTO_ICMP = 1,     /* Internet Control Message Protocol    */
#define IPPROTO_ICMP        IPPROTO_ICMP
  IPPROTO_IGMP = 2,     /* Internet Group Management Protocol   */
#define IPPROTO_IGMP        IPPROTO_IGMP
  IPPROTO_IPIP = 4,     /* IPIP tunnels (older KA9Q tunnels use 94) */
#define IPPROTO_IPIP        IPPROTO_IPIP
  IPPROTO_TCP = 6,      /* Transmission Control Protocol    */
#define IPPROTO_TCP     IPPROTO_TCP
...
```